# Getting all Wikipedia articles with coordinates inside London

Tags: python, openstreetmap, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Generally I want to get the links (and titles) of all Wikipedia articles with coordinates inside London. I tried using Google, but unfortunately did't come with proper search terms. Any hints?

[image: London map]

Comment: There is no MediaWiki API that will allow you to search within a shape. You will have to fetch all geocoded articles, and then check what coordinates are within your feature..

Answer (score 2):

*This is really just a collection of ideas that was too big for a comment.*

Your best bet is probably [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess). It's a semantic mirror of Wikipedia, with much more sophisticated query possibilities than Wikipedia's API has. As you can see in [this paper](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/C.B.Jones/articles/YounisJonesTanasescu-GIscience2012.pdf) it can handle fairly complex spatial queries, but you'll need to get into [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL). Here's a figure from that paper:

[image: Example SPARQL query]

That said, Wikipedia's API has a relatively new feature for spatial queries: [Showing nearby wiki information](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Showing_nearby_wiki_information). I don't think you can search in a polygon, but it's a good start.

Here's a previous answer I wrote about using `mwclient` to get the coordinates from articles, but that user had the advantage of having a list of articles to scrape.

[Geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/wikipedia/) might be able to help narrow down the search to geolocated articles. It wouldn't be too bad to check the 806,000 geolocated articles in English Wikipedia.

For performance reasons, and to avoid causing trouble for Wikipedia's servers, you might consider working from a dump of [Wikipedia](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/) or DBpedia.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a task for OpenStreetMap and [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

For constructing our query we go to [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu) (a nice frontend for Overpass API), open the *wizard* and enter "wikipedia=* in London" because we are interested in the [wikipedia tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:wikipedia).

The automagically generated and executed query will be this one:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “London” to search in
{{geocodeArea:London}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “wikipedia=*”
  node["wikipedia"](area.searchArea);
  way["wikipedia"](area.searchArea);
  relation["wikipedia"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

This will return too much elements, also heavily burdening your browser. And might fail because of the timeout being too low.

We modify it slightly. We increase the *timeout* and we remove the recursion step (`>;`) because we are only interested in the direct results and not any related objects. The resulting query will be this one:

```
[out:json][timeout:90];
// fetch area “London” to search in
{{geocodeArea:London}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “wikipedia=*”
  node["wikipedia"](area.searchArea);
  way["wikipedia"](area.searchArea);
  relation["wikipedia"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
out skel qt;
```

You can view the [result here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/enE).

Now there are various options to export it. On overpass turbo you can go to *export* and either safe the results directly to a file or get the raw query that is send to Overpass API. You can now run this query directly from your python script.

Note that there are different [output formats](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Choose_file_format) available: JSON, XML and CSV. And next to the Wikipedia tag you might also be interested in the [wikidata tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:wikidata).

Also note that this won't get you *all* Wikipedia pages with coordinates inside London, just the one that are contained in the OSM database.

Comment: Okay, in general you are awesome and adorable. The problem is that the results are a joke. OpenStreetMap is fantastic, but when it comes to that tag the quality is really low.

Comment: I haven't compared the coverage of the wikipedia tag but I guess you are right :/

Comment: the good  thing is - the quality has greatly improved in the last year, and now there are tools to query both wikidata and osm at once - https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Wikidata%2BOSM_SPARQL_query_service